# Reload page after applying commerce coupon

Tags: commerce

I'm quite obsessed on one page checkout using drupal commerce kickstart. I'm using commerce coupon(wonderful module) and we all know that there's a possibility that the order total price could be zero if you we apply a 100% coupon module. I see this post [Commerce - how to set no payment for free orders when 100% coupon applied](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101777/commerce-how-to-set-no-payment-for-free-orders-when-100-coupon-applied) and I guess we are having the same problem. I did not see any way to ajax refresh the payment method pane, and my last work around is to reload the entire page after applying coupons.

Is there a way to reload the entire page after applying coupons?

Thanks.

Comment: I've never used commerce, but you could check to see if there's a Rules Event for applying a coupon and go from there

Comment: @Geoff I already tried that option. I add a redirect action after applying coupon using rules. Unfortunately, it doesn't redirect or load to the page I specified. I guess it is because coupons is using ajax. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One solution here is to add a custom JS behavior to your module that looks for the AJAX callback context of applying a coupon. Upon such context, you can refresh the page or update the DOM as you see fit.

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {

    //Look for the context of a coupon form AJAX callback
    //If there's no error message, assume successful coupon application
    if($(context[0]).attr('id') == 'commerce-checkout-coupon-ajax-wrapper' && !$(context[0]).find('.messages').hasClass('error')) {
      //@TODO: Reload page or other JS to refresh coupon usage
    }
  }
};
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Very much appreciated @shawn. I found out that it is not needed to refresh the page or create a callback function to refresh the payment method pane. I just add a custom condition on Rules so Drupal will automatically skip the payment processing if the total amount of order is less than 0 or 0. Thank you so much for your response. Perhaps I can use this on other circumstances.